# overflow:auto not working when populating via ajax

Tags: css, ajax, overflow

I have a `<div>` element that is styled as `overflow:auto`.

This `<div>` element gets populated after document `load` through an `ajax` call like so:

```
<html>
<div class="overflow-auto"> <!-- content goes here --> </div>
</html>
```

I have an ajax call that populates it and, obviously, I want a scroll bar if needed.

However for some reason, once I populate it and there are more elements than fit inside the `<div>` height, it acts as `overflow:visible` and splatters all over my page.

I am assuming this has to do with the fact that the `<div>` element is styled on page load and the ajax call is called *after* the page is loaded and may not be thinking about the `overflow:auto` that was declared to the `css`.

I tried calling `$("overflow-auto").css("overflow","auto")` after the ajax call but this didn't seem to work.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: because `overflow:auto` effect only if you set `height` and `width`.

Comment: Thanks @mmativ - worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Height` or `Width` to your `Div` so `Overflow` can work.